# Create new folder in IntelliJ Idea to execute java files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the traditional `/src` directory which contains all of my java files. I have a lot of files already in `/src` I need to create sub-directories how do I do this in IntelliJ IDEA IDE without creating a new package? or another way? I have tried `mkdir` form the command line and from within the IDE but I always am creating packages entitled with the directory name. Is this best practice? The JavaDocs could be misleading with this convention?

**Update for context and clarity**

I'm enrolled in a Java class and I'm working on several example problems through chapters 1-18. After chapter 4 the amount of java files has tenfolded within my left pane project structure window. I would like to organize by creating sub-directory folders titled respectively for each chapter - I should create packages to accomplish this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you create new packages?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm just looking to organize the 20 and counting java files I have, is it proper to create package that is not really a package - is the definition of a programming package suppose to implement classes, code otherwise not present? Hence why I am weary of creating 'packages' when I merely want to organize

Comment: If you want to organize, you'll create logical packages which would then be in their own directories (although this isn't a strict requirement, it would be foolish to try to do otherwise). Sounds like you don't have a clean package structure.

Comment: Create another folders and mark them as source